# Docker Restart - Keep Environment Variables

Tags: java, docker

We have a Docker container that runs a Java server. Some environment variables are passed to the contained from the *run* command (e.g. `docker run -e INSTANCE_NAME=$INSTANCE_ID [...]`)

This works as expected, the server has access to the INSTANCE_NAME environment variable. However, if we stop the container and restart it, the environment variables are lost, the Java server cannot find INSTANCE_NAME. What is even more strange is that if we enter the container with `docker exec -it ID bash`, the environment variables are correctly set. So it seems that when restarting the container, the environment variable are set differently than during the first run with `docker run`.

Is anybody aware of such a thing? Is it simply a bad manipulation on our side?

Comment: I have not seen that.  Most likely error is in your script or java program. You could replace the "java" program with "env" command and provide the info to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind this post, I accidentally changed the starting script so that after the restart, the Java program was being run under sudo, having a different set of environment variables...